# Sharepoint error - I have no idea what to do, and no budget to fix it

Tags: search

I'm stuck with the below issue after we upgraded with sp1 and cumulative update march 2015. As I work for a charity and we don't have any budget any help will be appreciated.

> {"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"error\":{\"code\":\"-1,
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException\",\"message\":{\"lang\":\"en-US\",\"value\":\"An
>   unknown error occurred.\"},\"innererror\":{\"message\":\"An unknown
>   error
>   occurred.\",\"type\":\"Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException\",\"stacktrace\":\"
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchService.Execute[T](Action`1
>   initializer, Func`2 executor)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceServerStub.query_MethodProxy(SearchService
>   target, ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceServerStub.InvokeMethod(Object
>   target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection xmlargs, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object
>   target, String methodName, ClientValueCollection args, ProxyContext
>   proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.InvokeMethod(Boolean
>   mainRequestPath, Object value, ServerStub serverProxy, EdmParserNode
>   node, Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation methodInfo, Boolean
>   isExtensionMethod, Boolean isIndexerMethod)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPathMember(Boolean
>   mainRequestPath, String path, Object value, EdmParserNode node,
>   Boolean resourceEndpoint, MethodInformation& methodInfo)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.GetObjectFromPath(Boolean
>   mainRequestPath, String path, String pathForErrorMessage)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.Process()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest()\r\n
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Rest.RestService.ProcessQuery(Stream
>   inputStream, IList`1
>   pendingDisposableContainer)\",\"internalexception\":{\"message\":\"Search
>   has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned.
>   If the issue persists, please contact your
>   administrator.\",\"type\":\"Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.InternalQueryErrorException\",\"stacktrace\":\"
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.ThrowGenericQueryException(String
>   operationName)\\r\\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1
>   webServiceCall, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
>   wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String
>   operationName, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
>   wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1
>   webServiceCall)\\r\\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties
>   properties)\\r\\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()\\r\\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query
>   query)\\r\\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query
>   query)\\r\\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()\\r\\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPerxxxxxxx[T](Func`1
>   f)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery_Client(Query
>   query)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchService.b__a(KeywordQuery
>   query)\r\n at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchService.Execute[T](Action`1
>   initializer, Func`2
>   executor)\"}}}}","status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}

Thank you

Comment: could you please add more details, where you are getting this error? what sharepoint components stop working and what solution you applied so far?

Comment: Hi, The above message is in a 'Top Stories' web part. Most of the results I can find points to 'Search' being an issues. When I try to search for anything in the search centre I get an error stating 'Something when wrong"... "Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator.
Correlation ID: d1e4909d-a744-b030-e528-b9ee0992ef62" I'm not able to make sense of the correlation id.

Comment: Did you run the config wizard on all server in farm after installing the patches? If not then run it... Also in powershell run merge-splogfie command with correlation Id parameter to get the detailed info? Also try to reboot the servers

Comment: Have also notices this in CA: Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running.

Comment: I have set the memorylimit for noderunner to Zero and restarted the search service, still same issues

Comment: I asked u couple of weeks things could you plz response those

Answer (score 0):

You should

- set the max to 0.
- recycle the search host service.
- and run this cmdlet

  $UP = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where {$_.TypeName -like "Usage*"}
      $UP.Provision()

I don't know what the PS does, but it works.

Comment: What's the max Of !!!?